# Jupyter Notebook doesn't want to open

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

So I tried one time to open Jupyter after a closed and now its only the console that open

[image: here what happen]

Comment: have you tried launching jupyter notebook from cmd?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some days ago. Try to install again the anaconda because maybe it's a problem of an update. Otherwise I suggest you to work on Google Colab which is faster.